# Cannot install sqlsrv driver for PHP 5.5 on x64

Tags: php, sql-server-2012, driver

I got this to work on my x86 machine but for some reason my install procedure is not working for my x64 machine. My x64 machine is running SQL Server 2012 express and already has the SQL Server client installed. I downloaded a 3rd party driver for php 5.5 running on x86 machines and some people claimed that it worked on x64 as well. I got it to work on my x86 machine fine and I am using the slqsrv functions on it at the moment. However, I cannot get it to work even though I follow the same installation procedure on my x64 machine.

Procedure for php.ini

1. Change extension_dir to say extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"
2. Added the following lines to the extension section:

   extension = php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll;
   extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll;
3. moved the php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll files to C:\php\ext

And fail. I am thinking that the drivers just will not work on x64. Should I consider using an older version of php like php 5.3?

Comment: Did you restart the web server after making changes to `php.ini`? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, undefined function sqlsrv_connect

Comment: Did you edit the right php.ini? If you view a `phpinfo()` page it will show you what `php.ini` is being loaded.

Comment: loaded configuration file: "C:\php\php.ini" seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall apache 2.4 x64 and php 5.5 x64. Reinstall them as x86 not x64 and it works fine.

Comment: I am on a 32 bit machine. Both of these programs are installed with their 32bit versions.

Comment: check this:
https://thommck.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/how-to-add-a-path-to-the-system-variables-in-windows-2008-r2/